# gwt script injector not synchronous

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gwt

```
ScriptElement script = Document.get().createScriptElement();
script.setSrc(fileName);        
getBody().appendChild(script);
```

I use the above code to inject several javascript into gwt html but I realised it does not run in synchronous mode which causes some javascript to run before another javascript. Is there any solution towards this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to use the `ScriptInjector` class?

In case you define your script inside a Java class, you can use it in this way:

```
  String scriptBody = "var foo = ...";
  ScriptInjector.fromString(scriptBody).inject();
```

or, in case you want to load it from the server:

```
 ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://example.com/foo.js").setCallback(
   new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
   public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
     Window.alert("Script load failed.");
   }
   public void onSuccess(Void result) {
     Window.alert("Script load success.");
   }
 }).inject();
```

Important note: To ensure, that the script is loaded, you need to call `inject()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried ScriptInjector class from String but it loads the javascript in asynchronous mode. This caused an issue when one javascript need the JQuery to load before it , in order to load properly.

I tried readjust the sequence which is putting the JQuery on top of javascript while gwt needed time for the Jquery to load but the javascript already started to load. 

In order to solve this, I uses gwt timer to handle the script delay but this isn't a good approach so is there anyway to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: How do you load the jQuery script? Are you using a script tag?

Comment: yes, using script tag to load the JQuery and javascript.

Comment: I think that's your problem. Try loading the jquery script using the ScriptInjector. (and do not miss the inject() method).

Comment: @why-soserious You need to chain your script loads using the callback from the script injector; that's the reason they exist: so you're guaranteed that the script is loaded so you can start "using it", or load other scripts that depend on it.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer from my understanding, callback for script injector only works for  ScriptInjector.fromUrl not from String. While I needed it to load from String